# Framer Motion Exit animation not working React JS

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have created a modal and am using Framer motion to animate. The 'animate in' works fine but the exit animation does not, the modal and backdrop disappear instantly.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { solid } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro';
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

import './Modal.css';

const backdrop = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0 },
  visible: { opacity: 1 },
};

const modal = {
  hidden: {
    y: '-6vh',
    opacity: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    y: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: { delay: 0.2 },
  },
};

const Modal = ({ title, showWeatherModal, setShowWeatherModal }) => {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
      {showWeatherModal && (
        <motion.div
          key="weather-modal"
          className="modal-background"
          variants={backdrop}
          initial="hidden"
          animate="visible"
          exit="hidden"
        >
          <motion.div className="modal" variants={modal}>
            <div className="close-btn">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={solid('xmark')}
                color="var(--highlight)"
                onClick={() => setShowWeatherModal(false)}
                className="close-icon"
              />
            </div>

            <motion.div className="modal-title">{title}</motion.div>
            <motion.div className="modal-body">
              The weather for the event is going to be hot and sunny
            </motion.div>
            <motion.div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                onClick={() => setShowWeatherModal(false)}
                color="var(--highlight)"
                className="btn"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </motion.div>
          </motion.div>
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

The above is rendered in below component

```
const Events = () => {
  const {
    data: events,
    isPending,
    error,
  } = useFetch('/api/events/year/2022');

  const [showWeatherModal, setshowWeatherModal] = useState(false);

  if (showWeatherModal) {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
  }

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <h2 className="event">Events</h2>
      <div className="event-container">
        {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
        {isPending && <Spinner color="#FF533D" />}
        {events &&
          events.map((event) => (
            <EventCard
              key={event.id}
              event={event}
              setShowWeatherModal={setshowWeatherModal}
              showWeatherModal={showWeatherModal}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
      {showWeatherModal && (
        <Modal
          setShowWeatherModal={setshowWeatherModal}
          showWeatherModal={showWeatherModal}
          title="Weather"
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I've searched for a solution on SO and in the Framer docs and a lot of problems I have already sorted. Does anyone know why this code doesn't work correctly? Animate presence is wrapped around the conditional element and the only child of AnimatePresence has a key prop. What am i missing?

Comment: It does not seems to have any error, how is `<Modal />` placed though?

Comment: You're comment has pointed mein right direction, I had the modal component conditionally rendered on the within the Event element as well. I removed that and all works as expected. Thanks for the hint!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the modal component conditionally rendered on the within the Event element as well as well as within the Modal element. I removed the former and animation on exit works as expected now